# backbone.js + JQuery: 'this' reference not accessible in JQuery-Event-Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use backbone.js in my webapp. I have a View which uses the JQuery draggable plugin to make a div draggable:

```
var ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    //...
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");

    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
      // icanhaz
      this.el = ich.kinectdevtmpl();

      $(this.el).draggable({
         drag: function() { 
                alert(this.model);

         }
      });           

    return this;
  }
```

});

But in the drag event handler I can't access 'this.model' because 'this' do not refer to the view anymore. So, how can I access my View in the JQuery event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has changed and is no longer what you want.
you can assign this to a variable and use that instead.

```
var that = this;
$(this.el).draggable({
   drag: function() { 
          alert(that.model);

   }
});
```

Comment: Another way is to bind the function to the view: `drag: _.bind(this, function(){alert(this.model)})`

Comment: This is a much better practice, in my point of view, because it explicitly binds the function. Using a 'that' reference always looks like a hack to me.

Comment: And you should use this.$el instead of $(this.el) for better performance. ;)